# Launching Apps via RDweb Access not working

Tags: azure, windows-server-2012, azure-virtual-machine, remoteapp

I have created a Windows Server 2012 VM on Azure in its own Domain, running Active Directory.

It is also the host for:

- RD Gateway
- RD Licensing
- RD Web Access
- RD Connection Broker

It has been configured for Remote Desktop Session access to launch published apps.

Here is an overview of the deployment: http://screencast.com/t/NCn8xGFrnzU5

The issue I am facing is this:

While logged inside the Azure VM that is hosting the applications, I can:
Browse to the 'RD Web Access' URL
Log in to the RD Web page
Successfully launch the published apps

Here is a video of me doing the above while logged onto the Azure VM: http://screencast.com/t/PxZTcXmEl

However, if I attempt to do the above steps on any other PC, we can browse to the 'RD Web Access' URL and log in to the RD Web page BUT, when I attempt to launch the application, I get the error "Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons..........." (screenshot)

Here is a video of me doing the above on my local machine: http://screencast.com/t/zjKlPcok9Fn

I have run the RD License Diagnoser and everything seems to be OK: http://screencast.com/t/3c6qNfWno1u

Can anyone provide any suggestions on what could be the problem, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to let you know that i have resolved the issue. Essentially it was a windows firewall issue where even though the firewall rules were set up etc, i still needed to go to the control panel firewall menu (as opposed to the server dashboard firewall interface) and select the 'Allow apps through the firewall' option and then enable all apps and give permissions to all 'remote' options in this list. Obviously to enable the external machine to connect to the server i had to setup Self Signed certificates and make them trusted to avoid any authentication issues.

Michael.